# JQuery - using previously declared variables for a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

Have searched high an low for an answer without luck.

I am trying to pass a variable between two functions. The first function runs when the page loads, pulling settings from a google script file. I don't have any issues with this part. I am however, struggling with the second function which runs 'on click' and requires some variables from the first function.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(loadSettings)
           .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
           .withUserObject($('#button-bar').get())
           .getSettings();

    function loadSettings(settings) {

    $("select").data("option",settings.userInput1);

      };

    $('#add1').click(function(){

    var option0 = $("select").data("option");}

    ...etc. 

    })

</script>
```

Comment: Define the variable as global

Comment: Which variable you want to use again?

Comment: @Ritz I am trying to reuse settings.userInput1 . I tried defining a global variable but whatever I have tried didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `settings.userInput1` is a string. Try the below

```
<script>
var userInput ="";   

$(function() {

        google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(loadSettings)
           .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
           .withUserObject($('#button-bar').get())
           .getSettings();

    function loadSettings(settings) {
     userInput = settings.userInput1;
    $("select").data("option",settings.userInput1);

      };

    $('#add1').click(function(){
    //you can now use userInput in this function
    var option0 = $("select").data("option");}

    ...etc. 

    })
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I just tried it again. I'm stumped why not though!

Comment: Try adding console.log and also check the `type of` that variable

Comment: thank you @Ritz . Much appreciated. I had a error further down in the script which was stopping the global variable from actually working. Your solution above was correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

if other solutions are not working then you should go this way -

- Make a hidden field
- store that variables value in that hidden field
- in the next function get the value from that field
  `$("#hiddenfield_id").val();`

Comment: Thank you. Very creative way of doing it.